# How to center expanded title in a CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to center the toolbar title when the layout is expanded, this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the **expandedTitleGravity** to the **CollapsingToolbarLayout** as an app attribute:

```
app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
```

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"            
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: I didn´t see that attribute in the doc, is it new?

Comment: I am not sure. I thought it has always been there. But I could be wrong.

Comment: app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizonta | bottoml" if you other views inside your CTL to make it appear just right

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the values of these two attributes

```
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
```

in

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"       
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp">
```

Comment: This did not center the title for me.